# URL encoding inside browsers

Tags: javascript, browser, encoding

I was reading about URL encode inside browser. I know it is done to send URL over internet. But when I see this encoding inside address bar, it seems that only some characters being encoded. However, when I copy and paste inside notepad, all SPECIAL CHARACTERS seem to be encoded. What we see in address browser is fake? Actually all characters are encoded? Do browsers use javascript function encodeURI() for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, what the address bar shows is often not the actual URL. Most browsers decode encoded characters to display a more friendly looking URL, and to allow you to read the URL as actual characters, which may or may not be useful.

However, some characters look extremely similar to other characters, like the cyrillic letter А (U+0410) which is virtually indistinguishable from the latin letter A (U+0041). To avoid confusion and/or phishing attacks, letters which are easily confused may not be decoded.